# How to run virtualized linux inside OS X?

Tags: linux, macos, mac, virtualization

I want to run a virtualized Linux (possibly also OpenSolaris) on my Core Duo Mac that runs OS X 10.4.

How to do it? What are the possible solutions? What are pros and cons of those solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VMware Fusion ($80) or Virtualbox ($0) will allow you to do this.

VMware's advantage is portability and ubiquity, and I find it to be very robust. Virtualbox is free, which is hard to argue with, though I don't know if it will run OpenSolaris.

Comment: I'm having some success with VirtualBox, though I only need it occasionalyy to check the cross-platformness of some code changes or to reproduce OS dependent bug reports. Haven't tries VMware.

Comment: I find WMware Fusion much better then Parallels.

Comment: It seems that OpenSolaris runs within Virtualbox. Link: http://dlc.sun.com/osol/docs/content/IPS/virtualbox.html

Comment: Considering that Sun bought out the VirtualBox team, I'd find it ironic if it didn't run OpenSolaris.

Comment: I successfully run OpenSolaris (and Windows 7 RC) within VirtualBox running on a Mac (under Mac OS X 10.5, but it should run fine under Mac OS X 10.4 - on Intel - as well.)

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).  And here's a [Gizmodo Howto](http://gizmodo.com/5383982/how-to-virtualize-any-os-for-free) (although it's Windows on a Mac, the principal is the same).